# Did anybody make up their own problems instead of studying with the ones that are in a textbook?

Tags: self-learning, problem-solving, education

I recently tried studying by creating my own problems and then trying to solve them. Sometimes they can't be solved, but I have seen that it's a good practice since the problems I make are usually harder.

Did anybody try to do the same?

Comment: Is there anyone who has read ***all*** the text books before stating a problem not mentioned ***anywhere***?

Comment: IMO I would not recommend doing so when first studying a topic. Esp with good textbooks, the problems showcase how the ideas/concepts are useful tools in a mathematicians bag of tricks. Maybe after you've built up your intuition, you can then try creating your own problems, though I'd argue that your time is much better spent finding a textbook with better problems.